# Смысл использования headless браузеров в процессе тестирования

Tags: юнит-тесты, test-driven-development

Какой смысл имеет использование headless браузеров (PhantomJS) в процессе разработки через тестирование модулей JS, если использование `jsdom`/`node` и так дает быстро работающие и легко настраиваемые тесты?

Ответ консультанта был очень общий: вопрос перехода на браузерное/PhantomJs тестирование во многом зависит от нужд и специфики проекта.

Т.е. он не знает.

Зачем тогда создавали headless тестирование?